# how to make Wall Painting Application in android

Tags: android

How to make a wall painting application in android?
give me some guidelines.

i try to use image processing, but it result not met the quality.

Comment: you can start looking into openCV

Comment: If you just need to paint on an image, renderscript might help, there are various paint algorithms available online

Comment: @ Sarthak Mittal  thank you.